# get value parameter from url codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri, codeigniter-3, request-uri

hello I want to ask getting value parameter from url to my controller

I set redirecting url from javascript like this,

```
window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url().'index.php/form_tambahasset'?>' + '?lang=' + lg + '&lat=' +lt;
```

and I need to bring parameter `lang` and `lat` to my next page,

```
http://localhost/BTS_CI/index.php/form_tambahasset
```

if I set redirect url to be like this,

```
http://localhost/BTS_CI/index.php/form_tambahasset/lang/107.39410400390625/lat/-6.671700384923497
```

it must be 404 page not found.

how can I get value parameter `lang` and `lat` ? my position of my `$config['uri_protocol']` at `REQUEST_URI` now but I was try change into `PATH_INFO` it doesn't work to me.

I was try `$this->uri->segment(3, 0);` and `parse_str($_GET['lat'], $_GET);` still doesn't work to get my param.

my page of

```
http://localhost/BTS_CI/index.php/form_tambahasset?lang=107.39410400390625&lat=-6.671700384923497
```

is doing fine, but I need to get my param value

any solution for my problem? please help me. thank you

Comment: Just a tip; use `site_url` instead of `base_url` and please use this format: `site_url('index.php/form_tambahasset')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to look at the documentation.

```
$this->input->get('lang', TRUE); // TRUE is for XSS filtering
$this->input->get('lat', TRUE); // TRUE is for XSS filtering
```

[Codeigniter Input Class - Using POST, GET, COOKIE, or SERVER Data](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html?highlight=input#using-post-get-cookie-or-server-data)

Comment: thank you, I didn't look Input Class documentation. And I just know it can be get param without declare server method.